# How to update a Composite foreign key

Tags: mysql

This is my parent table

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `delete` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`delete`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my child table

```
CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_delete` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_if_delete_idx` (`parent_id`,`parent_delete`),
  CONSTRAINT `parent_if_delete` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`, `parent_delete`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`, `delete`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Output which I am getting:

```
+----+--------+
| id | delete |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      0 |
|  2 |      0 |
+----+--------+
CHILD
+-----+-----------+---------------+
| id  | parent_id | parent_delete |
+-----+-----------+---------------+
| 1   |         1 |             0 |
| 2   |         2 |             0 |
| 3   |         1 |             0 |
| 4   |         2 |             0 |
+-----+-----------+---------------+
```

If I update parent id and parent delete flags, my child row parent_id is updated but my delete flag doesn't.

Comment: I doubt about it, have a look at your foreign key constraint: `ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`

Comment: thanks vhu i got the answer....